# Spark not using Yarn Cluster Resources

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I'm trying to run a Python script using Spark (1.6.1) on an Hadoop cluster (2.4.2). The cluster was installed, configured and managed using Ambari (2.2.1.1).

I have a cluster of 4 nodes (each 40Gb HD-8 cores-16Gb RAM).

My script uses `sklearn` lib: so in order to parallelize it on spark I use `spark_sklearn` lib (see it on https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-spark.html).

At this point I tried to run the script with:

```
spark-submit spark_example.py --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 8 --num-executor-core 4 --executor-memory 2G
```

but it runs always on localhost with only one executor.

[image]

Also from Ambari dashboard I can see that only one node of the cluster is resource-consuming. And also trying different configurations (executors, cores) the execution time is the same.

**UPDATE**

This is Yarn UI Nodes screenshot:

[image]

And this is Scheduler Tab:

[image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you post screen shot of nodes and scheduler tab of yarn UI also.

Comment: @shekhar I added the image. Is that you want?

Comment: can you submit using "yarn-cluster" instead of "yarn" and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @GameOfThrows I just did it, but I found no differences

Comment: can you also post screen shot of scheduler tab

Comment: @shekhar just done it. Thanks a lot

Comment: can you see it in application list?? hope you are submitting job from yarn cluster.

Comment: @shekhar It isn't present in application list. I'm submitting job from the third node of the cluster (where I installed all needed python libs)

Comment: have you declared HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR env variable on this third node of cluster?? Spark requires that the HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR environment variable point to the directory containing the client-side configuration files for the cluster. These configurations are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager.

Comment: Are these configs managed in Ambari?

Comment: I don't know, have never used it.

Comment: If it can helps: if I run `spark_shell`I see it in Yarn UI Applications Log.

Comment: and earlier you were not seeing it, right?? are you getting any error now??

Comment: @shekhar see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond myself thanks to an answer to the same question on [Hortonworks Community.](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/32656/spark-not-using-yarn-cluster-resources.html#comment-32683)

Setting the parameter `MASTER="yarn-cluster"` (or `MASTER="yarn-client"`) seems to work: now I see the application reports in Spark History and YARN History UIs.

[image]

**ps:** seems the params passed via command line (e.g.: `--num-executors 8--num-executor-core 4--executor-memory 2G`) are not taken in consideration. Instead, if I set the **executors param** in "`spark-env template`" filed of Ambari, the params are taken in consideration. Anyway now it works :)

I hope this helps someone in the future.